# How does C++ OOP works?

Tags: c++, oop, ram

So I was playing with C++ features and I found that there is a big difference between C-style function pointers and C++ methods. Here is what do I mean:

```
typedef struct _myStruct {
    void (*myFunctionOne)();
    void(*myFunctionTwo)();
    void(*myFunctionThree)();
} myStruct;
```

Size is 3 * 4 = 12 bytes.

```
typedef struct _emptyStruct {
} emptyStruct;
```

Size is 1 byte.

```
class myClass {
     void myMethodOne();
     void myMethodTwo();
     void myMethodThree();
};
```

Size is 1 byte, like this is an empty struct.

Why is it empty? If C++ methods are not function pointers, how do they are implemented? How does class "know" about it's methods, if it doesn't have any pointers? This question doesn't actually distrubs me a lot, but it arouses my curiosity.

Comment: Member functions work the same way regular old free functions. You don't need a function pointer to call those either.

Comment: Non-virtual member functions are just functions in a scope -- no pointers in the instance. Virtual functions will not have a pointer for each function in the instance either, just one vtable pointer.

Comment: This is a **big** subject.  You might be better served getting a [nice C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) that would explain this entire side of C++

Comment: On an unrelated note, the size of you `_myStruct` structure isn't guaranteed to be 12 bytes. It can be more (or less, though that's not very likely).

Comment: Try declaring the methods as virtual and run your test again.

Comment: Keep in mind that the function pointers used in the c `struct` serve a different purpose then non-`virtual` member functions in c++. You can approximate it with `virtual` member functions, which is likely to increase the size of your type slightly. The most common implementation adds a single pointer to a shared table of function pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Member functions are *functions*. They are implemented as functions. They are not data and are not stored inside the structure. They are just *declared* there.

If you have

```
class myClass {
     void myMethodOne();
     void myMethodTwo();
     void myMethodThree();
};
```

and then another class

```
class myOtherClass {
     void myMethodOne();
     void myMethodFortyTwo();
};
```

then `myMethodOne` from `myClass` and `myOtherClass` don't conflict, because they actually have different names: `myClass::myMethodOne` and `myOtherClass::myMethodOne`.

```
myClass myVar;
myVar.myMethodOne();
```

This knows to call `myClass::myMethodOne` and not `myOtherClass::myMethodOne` because of the *type* of `myVar`. It is `myClass`, so the method of `myClass` is called.

Virtual functions work differently: they *are* stored in each object, though usually indirectly (often as a pointer to an entire bunch of functions pointers), This way the size of each object doesn't grow as we add more virtual functions.

Comment: I would change the wording "Virtual functions are stored in each object". It is VERY misleading, especially since you proceed to describe the correct  implementation (pointer to vtable) immediately after.

Comment: @GonenI Any implementation is correct as long as it's according with the standard. Vtables is one implementation, there are others.

Answer (score 4):

In the structure with pointers to functions, each pointer is a *member variable*. The C++ class doesn't have any member variables, it is, as you say, *empty*.

Member function are not the same as member variables.